# Unexpected end of file looking for </head> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have already having a head tag on my aspx page. Now I am using another head tag in the form of text shown below.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
filteredText = filteredText.replace("<head>", '<head><base target="_blank"/>');       
</head>
```

filteredText is my string collection in which iam replacing the values.
Now iam getting parsor error when i run the application.This might because two head on     same page

> **Parser Error Message:** Unexpected end of file looking for  tag.

Anyone Knows...

Comment: So have you tried removing one of the <head> tags ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be written like this.....

```
      filteredText = filteredText.replace('<head></head>', '<head>' +'<base          
      target="_blank"/>'+'</head>');
```

Finally the above statements works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are replacing head tag in between head tag. Following string causes problem.

```
filteredText = filteredText.replace("<head>", '<head><base target="_blank"/>')
```

See the string you are replacing. Instead of doing like this. You can use another way.

```
<head ID="head1" runat="server">
</head>
```

Now in page_load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       head1.InnerText =@ "<base target='_blank'/>";
}
```